# How to play Youtube video on Java, Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have following code for playing video:

```
private void loadPlayer() {
        Intent youtube = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CES7xNy70hU"));   
        startActivityForResult(youtube, 100);
}
```

But when player finishes showing video, it won't close itself and user need to press `Back` button. I need that player will close himself automatically after end of video.

How can I do it?

Answer (score -1):

try to check for if player is playing

```
if(mPlayer.isPlaying())
     {
         mPlayer.stop();
         finish();
     }
```

Comment: What do you mean? I start Youtube player through Intent. How can I invoke "isPlaying()" method?