# How can I use Intent on Java, Android?

Tags: java, android

I have written the following code for playing video:

```
private void loadPlayer() {
        Intent youtube=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CES7xNy70hU")); 
        startActivityForResult(youtube, 100);
}
```

My problem is that when the player finishes showing the video it won't close itself and the user needs to press the back button. I need the player to close itself automatically after the video has finished playing. How can I accomplish this?

The target platform is Android - 2.2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play Youtube video on Java, Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939668/how-to-play-youtube-video-on-java-android)

Answer (score 1):

Create an activity that just displays a VideoViewer.  Play the video from there.  Implement a listener for the completion of the video.  Then call finish within there to end the activity:

```
videoViewer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
        {               
            finish();
        }

    });
```

This will return you to the previous Activity.

Comment: I use Youtube player through Intent, not VideoView, it's important. Therefore, I can't use Listeners.

Comment: That's why you shouldnt do that. Activities that you start don't autoclose themselve, unless you create that activity yourself and customize it to close oncompletion like the example of SBerg413